# PHP Вывод многоуровневого списка из базы данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql, список

Есть таблица `Категории` в базе данных следующего вида: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Где `parent` - это `id` родительского элемента. Если у элемента нет родителя, то `parent` = 0.
Необходимо вывести содержимое таблицы в виде списка, но я не могу сообразить как это сделать.
Как это должно выглядеть:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пока вывел только верхний уровень:

```
include("db.inc");
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent='0'", $db);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
<ul>
<?php 
do 
{
echo
'<li id="super-menu"><a href="view_cat.php?cat='.($row["id"]).'" 
id="super">'.$row["title"].'</a></li>';  
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res));
?>  
</ul>
```

Comment: уже пора забыть о  mysql_.......  в PDO это проще и лучше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да всё проще чем кажеться в базу заносите `id`, `cat_name`, `level`, `sort` 
где:

1. cat_name - имя категории
2. level - уровень
3. sort - порядок расположение

далее берём выбираем:

```
` select * from `tree` order by `sort` asc;
```

в результате получаем массив вида:

```
array(
  array('1', 'test cat', '1', '1'),
  array('2', 'test cat', '2', '2'),
  array('3', 'test cat', '2', '3'),
  array('4', 'test cat', '1', '4'),
  array('5', 'test cat', '1', '5'),
)
```

далее, нам необходимо отрендерить, сформируем простую разметку:

```
<?php
echo '<div>';
foreach ($result as $res) {
    echo '<div class="level-' . $res['level'] . '>' . $res['cat_name'] . '</div>';
}
```

и после уже опишем в css как хотим разложить получившееся дерево:

```
.level-1 {
  position:absolute;
  left: 5px;
}


.level-2 {
  position:absolute;
  left: 10px;
}


.level-3 {
  position:absolute;
  left: 15px;
}
```

таким образом мы получим простую прямолинейную логику скрипта и древовидное представление. В действительности не обязательно хранить дерево как есть мы можем просто взять прямолинейную структуру, и сместив некоторые её элементы на некое число в право или в лево, тем самым получить представления дерева.

p.s. Я бэкэнд программист, по этому не могу провести полностью css и js код для реализации такого подхода, да и не сталбы потому как время и работа, а решение вопроса тянет на статью о построение диревьев.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел здесь https://webformyself.com/vyvod-mnogourovnevogo-menyu-s-neogranichennym-urovnem-vlozhennosti/
Осталось придумать как задать `id` элементам верхнего уровня